# PIVOT in SQL returning may rows that aren't needed as NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

Apologize if this is a duplicate, but my scenario is very specific to the examples provided.

What is wrong with this PIVOT Logic that is causing it to return all the un-needed nulls instead of just returning the 1 row with needed columns.
(been starring at it too long. )

```
SELECT ENTITY_VAL, [12],[11],[10],[9],[8],[7],[6],[5],[4],[3],[2],[1]
    FROM
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, D) + 1, 0)),121) DESC) ID 
    ,DATEPART(YEAR, D) YR
    ,DATEPART(MONTH, D) MNTH
    --,RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, D) AS VARCHAR(02)), 2) MNTH2
    ,CONVERT(DATE, D, 101) FIRSTOFMONTH
    ,CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, D) + 1, 0)),121) LASTOFMONTH
    , 1111111 ENTITY_VAL
    FROM
        (
          SELECT D = DATEADD(MONTH, XM.RN, @StartDate)
          FROM 
          (
            SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) 
              RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AO.[object_id])
            FROM sys.all_objects AS AO
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS AO2
            -- on my system this would support > 5 million days
            ORDER BY AO.[object_id]
          ) AS XM
        ) AS XY
    --ORDER BY LASTOFMONTH ASC
    ) AS BASE
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(FIRSTOFMONTH) FOR ID IN ([12],[11],[10],[9],[8],[7],[6],[5],[4],[3],[2],[1])
    ) AS PVT
```

I get this (NOT what I want):

```
ENTITY_VAL  12         11         10         9          8          7          6          5          4          3          2          1
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1111111     2016-11-01 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       2016-12-01 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       2017-01-01 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-02-01 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-03-01 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-04-01 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-05-01 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-06-01 NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-07-01 NULL       NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-08-01 NULL       NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-09-01 NULL
1111111     NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       2017-10-01
```

Instead of this (what I'm wanting):

```
ENTITY_VAL  12         11         10         9          8          7          6          5          4          3          2          1
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1111111     2016-11-01 2016-12-01 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01 2017-04-01 2017-05-01 2017-06-01 2017-07-01 2017-08-01 2017-09-01 2017-10-01
```

Comment: I wont debug the code. But pivot is straight forward. You have the data in a format and convert to the pivot format. So I recommend you debug your sub query to make sure the data is on the right format. Also simplify your code and test each small part separated. Check the [manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Did you saw the example? Rewrite `BASE` as a CTE and do `SELECT * FROM BASE`

Comment: Insight to your comments, the alias wouldn't matter, nor did I want * as it seems that wouldn't take away from the excess of what it was trying to display.

However I do THANK YOU for the spark of giving me the idea with "small part separated".

Comment: I didn't imply alias matter, I mean separate the parts so you can debug it more easily. Glad you can solve it :)

Comment: understood, I tend to change Alias/words a lot for a better way to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, It was the excessive columns "bloating" the PIVOT.

Updated logic:

```
SELECT ENTITY_VAL, [12],[11],[10],[9],[8],[7],[6],[5],[4],[3],[2],[1]
    FROM
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, D) + 1, 0)),121) DESC) ID         
    ,CONVERT(DATE, D, 101) FIRSTOFMONTH
    ,1111111 ENTITY_VAL
    FROM
        (
          SELECT D = DATEADD(MONTH, XM.RN, @StartDate)
          FROM 
          (
            SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) 
              RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AO.[object_id])
            FROM sys.all_objects AS AO
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS AO2
            -- on my system this would support > 5 million days
            ORDER BY AO.[object_id]
          ) AS XM
        ) AS XY
    --ORDER BY LASTOFMONTH ASC
    ) AS BASE
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(FIRSTOFMONTH) FOR ID IN ([12],[11],[10],[9],[8],[7],[6],[5],[4],[3],[2],[1])
    ) AS PVT
```

Which returns:

```
ENTITY_VAL  12         11         10         9          8          7          6          5          4          3          2          1
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1111111     2016-11-01 2016-12-01 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01 2017-04-01 2017-05-01 2017-06-01 2017-07-01 2017-08-01 2017-09-01 2017-10-01
```